# How to calculate a relative URL to a relative URL in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, uri

I have a "base URL" (which is relative itself) and a "child URL" which is also relative, to the "base URL". I want to properly combine these. For example:

```
"some/path/here" + "../other/path" => "some/other/path"
```

How can I do this in .NET? The [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hst1w91(v=vs.110).aspx) class requires the first Uri to be absolute.

**Added:** More examples, to clarify.

```
"contents/styles/style.css" + "image.jpg" => "contents/styles/image.jpg"
"contents/folder/style.css" + "../image.jpg" => "contents/image.jpg"
"contents/folder/style.css" + "../images/image.jpg" => "contents/images/image.jpg"
```

In other words, in the original example, since `here` didn't have a trailing slash, it should be treated as a file. Hence, `..` moves to the folder `some`.

Comment: Do you mean `"some/path/here" + "../../other/path" => "some/other/path"`?

Comment: @artm - No. I'll give more examples.

Comment: Please explain better your example. It is not so clear to me and I think to others also. Thank you.

Comment: @MSX - There you go.

Comment: @MSX - Hmm, probably not THAT bad. It can be split nicely along some delimiters, and then I only need to iterate through the path and process the special cases of `.` and `..`.

Comment: @Vilx: Actually I deleted my comment an instant before you posted yours, since I realized there are simpler ways to do it. However, by parsing I meant exactly what you suggested. Maybe I should be more careful when using some terms as in computer science they have well-defined meanings :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder();
Uri baseuri = builder.Uri;
builder.Path = "some/path/here";
Uri finalUri = baseuri.MakeRelativeUri(new Uri(builder.Uri, "..\\other\\path"));
```

or

```
Uri finalUri = baseuri.MakeRelativeUri(new Uri(builder.Uri, "file"));
```